# Using a functor

Tags: prolog

Following code accepts a index , a list and it deletes every nth occurance of that index in the list and returns a new list.

```
deleteNTerm(N,L1,L2) :- deleteNTerm(L1,N,L2,N).
deleteNTerm([],_,[],_).
deleteNTerm([_|Xs],N,Ys,1) :- deleteNTerm(Xs,N,Ys,N).
deleteNTerm([X|Xs],N,[X|Ys],K) :- K > 1, K1 is K - 1, deleteNTerm(Xs,N,Ys,K1).
```

So for the following query

```
?- deleteNTerm(2,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Result).
Result = [1,3,5,7].
```

However I want my code to accept a functor instead so i get

```
?-deleteNterm(2,f(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),Result).
Result f(1,3,5,7)
```

How to achieve this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break down a term into its functor and arguments using the (appropriately named) predicate `functor`.  This being prolog, it is also used to build a term from those components.  For example: `functor(A,f,3)` will yield `A = f(_G2130, _G2131, _G2132)`.

Actually, what would be more helpful would be `=..`:

```
3 ?- f(1,3,5,7) =.. X.
X = [f, 1, 3, 5, 7].

4 ?- X =.. [f,1,3,5,7].
X = f(1, 3, 5, 7).
```

Comment: i usually wouldn’t ask for code but i am quite new to prolog would highly appreciate if you can show me how it's done.

Comment: This user posts questions, gets an immediate upvote, and then deletes it again. [Last example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220326/retrieve-index-of-some-element-in-a-list). So expect it to be deleted again.

Comment: i figured out the answer that's why. what's wrong with deleting a question? you can check my history i have always accepted answers.

Comment: @user2733436: it's not funny if you got and answer ; and then delete it.

Comment: @false if someone had answered it i would have kept it anyway but if no one answered whats the point in keeping the question? its a PROBLEM if i deleted it when someone answered it. who said it's funny?

Comment: @false No I did not get an answer the person merely suggested something not an answer...